# pipe or send strings with socat/netcat with a pause

Tags: linux, bash, shell, socat

i capture unbuffered codes from ttyUSB0 as an string though hexdump'ing

```
/usr/bin/stdbuf -o0 /bin/busybox hexdump -v -e '12/1 "%02x" "\n"' /dev/ttyUSB0
```

with example-output like this (without quotes): "20303830303e353a30373220"

Now i am helpless:

I want a loop to netcat/socat the first capture (maybe with read ?) to another host, than a  slight pause e.g 10 sec before the next capture is send.

i searched for an elegant line with socat, but all my piping-examples failed. Seems some problems of understanding the subshell-processes.. and lack of experience. anybody a hint?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me with my mouse as input:

```
sudo stdbuf -o0 hexdump -v -e '12/1 "%02x" "\n"' /dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-if02-mouse | (while true; do read buf; echo $buf; sleep 1; done) | nc localhost 8008
```

I believe there could be a better implementation of what I do in the while-loop...

I'm able to get the input from my mouse with a previously-started

```
nc -l localhost 8008
```

Comment: sorry, not working for me. i'am investigating, but a ".../dev/ttyUSB0 | cat - " works, your example with my ttyUSB= not ... something with subshells or an hidden CR/LF in my string?

Comment: the example looked reasonable, so i investigated why its not working in my environment. i am running openwrt wich uses a busybox-integrated ash shell. maybe there are limits/[ash differences](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/#busybox)  with this? even piping with "| cat - " doesnt work as expected.. hmmm? (this redirection doesnt work also ... >> output.txt ... hmmm? i am lost ..

Comment: to bring myself light into the dark, i looked into ash-specifics...[Note that unlike some other shells, each process in the pipeline is a child of the invoking shell (unless it is a shell builtin, in which case it executes in the current shell -- but any effect it has on the environment is wiped)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ash.htm)

Comment: The example output suggests that there aren't newlines in the input - thus, `read` wouldn't return. If the strings are terminated by space, try `read -d' '`.